# How to create multiple instances of a class in extjs

Tags: extjs, extjs3

I create a class of `Button` and I want that button will appear on number of selection in checkbox. Right now button is appearing only one even though I selected multiple checkbox. 
So far I done

1. I creating button class.
2. Added into an array
3. Placing this array in items of panel.
4. Button class

   ```
   Record =  Ext.extend(Ext.Container,{    
   initComponent: function(){
   var p=this;
   p.bodyPadding = 5;
   p.margin = '5 5 0 3';
   p.layout = 'anchor';
   p.items = [{
       xtype: 'button',
       text : 'Hello
   }];
   Record.superclass.initComponent.apply(this, arguments); }});
   ```
5. Adding into array in function :

   `getRecords: function () {
    var RecItems[];
   recLength = Ext.getCmpBy('Rec').length
   var clsName;
       clsName = new Record (),
       for(var i=0;i<recLength; i++){
           var item = Ext.create(clsName,{
           });
           RecItems.push(item);
       }
       return RecItems;
   }`
6. Calling this in panel

   `{xtype:'panel',
       title : "Records",
       bodyStyle: 'background: #dfe8f6;border:#dfe8f6;',
       autoScroll: true,
       region: 'center',
       layout:{
           type: 'anchor',
           pack: 'start',
           align: 'stretch'
       },
       items: p.getRecords()
   }`

Comment: This doesn't make sense: `clsName = new Record (),` `var item = Ext.create(clsName,{` clsName is already a component instance. I can't remember if Ext 3 had `Ext.create`, from memory it didn't.

Comment: It is creating a class instant by this.

Comment: It's not, that's what `new` does.

Comment: Sorry, It is creating an object of Record. Also when I am calling in `panel` item it available, but in UI it is showing one one element. not All.

Comment: @EvanTrimboli Also can you please suggest me any way by which I can place multiple `button` or `textarea` in one component in ExtJS 3